# SPO Modern List - How to make the Attachments field mandatory?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, attachments

I would like to ask if there is a way to make the Attachments field required in a **Modern Experience List**, either if it's possible to set the column order of this field in **"New Form"** to be the second field not the last?

Please have a look at this screenshot below:
[image: Screenshot]

If it's possible can you please provide an example and explain in detail how to achieve it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no method to make the Attachments column required in Modern Experience.

By default, the Attachments column is not available in Column ordering of List Settings, So there is no method to change the order of Attachments column in "New Form" Modern Experience.

Answer (score 1):

This question looks old but answer might be helpful of someone here,

To make Attachments column required in Modern Experience, go to the list setting --> click any column, on the top url , change the name of the column to Attachments, you can make the column required their