# Attachments are mandatory in the SharePoint web version but not in the app

Tags: powerapp

As you can see the attachment is mandatory in Sharepoint web but is not in app. What can be done?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your "web form" has been customized by a **Power Apps canvas form**. So this not something by default, as attachments are not mandatory for the web form. That's explain why the mobile form is not mandatory as well.

**It's not possible to make attachments mandatory out-of-the box.**

Sources:

- [SPO Modern List - How to make the Attachments field mandatory?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276502/spo-modern-list-how-to-make-the-attachments-field-mandatory)
- [Make attachement option Mandatory](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/make-attachement-option-mandatory/m-p/1222111)
- [Make the attachments field mandatory](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Make-the-attachments-field-mandatory/td-p/2066150)

Comment: My attachments are mandatory in web form, even in the web version open from mobile but not in the app.

Comment: Yes because you customize the behaviour. It's not possible to make attachments mandatory out of the box. The mobile app cannot use the customized form.